# VueJs computed method error: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my pseudo code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {     
    words: [{name:'1'},  {name:'2'}, {name:'3'},{name:'4'},{name:'5'},{name:'6'}],
  },
  computed: {
    paginatedWords: function (words) {
      return vm.words.slice(2, 2);
    }
  }
});
```

I want to show only a portion of `words` with `v-for`,
Here is the Html:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="w in paginatedWords"> @{{w.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

But console gives me this error :

> Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of
>   undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Vue instance is being called vm, yet while you are declaring that instance, you then refer to vm within it. Do you intend to refer to "this" instead?

Comment: @ChrisCousins I think using `vm` inside Vue instance is ok.

Comment: No, using the name of the instance within its own definition is not ok. Hence why you got undefined for vm...

Comment: @ChrisCousins thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this`, not `vm`.

```
paginatedWords: function () {
  return this.words.slice(2, 2);
}
```

Also, `slice(2,2)` will return an empty array. The first argument is where to start and the second is where to end. See [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Finally, the `words` argument is ignored.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',

  data: {
    words: [{
      name: '1'
    }, {
      name: '2'
    }, {
      name: '3'
    }, {
      name: '4'
    }, {
      name: '5'
    }, {
      name: '6'
    }],

  },

  computed: {
    paginatedWords: function() {
      return this.words.slice(2, 4);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="w in paginatedWords"> {{w.name}} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yeahh, i was typing, you're very fast, bro hahaha

Comment: thank you, solved, but what is the reason ?  I thought it is a good practice to avoid `this` collision inside callbacks

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki there is no problem using `this` in your Vue code when used correctly. It is, in fact, very unusual to use a variable declared outside the Vue inside it the way you were attempting.